# Why wont my code calculate total prices and count the amount of coffees sold?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My Code below is not calculating the subtotal and gst of the order of the coffees, and I'm pretty sure I defined the variables but they are returning as not defined.

Also, A running total is meant to be kept for the end of the day summary, but it seems unable to count the number of coffee types ordered, as well as presenting the total price for the day.

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

tot_l_cap = 0
tot_r_cap = 0
tot_l_esp = 0
tot_r_esp = 0
tot_l_lat = 0
tot_r_lat = 0
tot_l_iced_c_ic = 0
tot_r_iced_c_ic = 0
tot_l_iced = 0
tot_r_iced = 0

print(Fore.BLUE + 'Welcome to 4Shore Cafe!')
print('We are happy to be of your assistance today.')
print('Please select from our fabulous menu below: ')
print('        ')
print('        ')
#Warning that customers must enter an integer - which is associated with the coffee they wish to purchase.
print('Please be advised to enter all coffee choices with the integer they are associated with :)')
print('        ')
#Menu for the customers to choose from:
print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------') 
print('1. Cappuccino:       |Regular: $4.40         |Large: $4.95')
print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print('2. Espresso:         |Regular: $3.60         |Large: $4.15')
print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')                
print('3. Latte:            |Regular: $3.85         |Large: $4.40')
print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print('4. Iced Coffee With ice-cream and cream:          |Regular: $4.40         |Large: $4.95')
print('5. Iced Coffee Without:                           |Regular: $3.85         |Large: $4.40' )
print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')

#Creates a function that enables the customer to enter their order.
def order():
    #Global vairables are created, as the variables the customer inputs are used outside of this function.
    global coff_type
    global coff_size
    global quant_coff
    #The customer inputs their order with coffee type, size and quantity they want.
    coff_type = int(input("What coffee would you like to order? "))
    coff_size = int(input('Would you like the size to be regular or large? '))
    quant_coff = int(input('How many would you like to order? '))
    return coff_type, coff_size, quant_coff
order()

#Changes the text of the order size to lower so that the code can be executed.
#coff_size = coff_siz.lower()

def coff_order():
    global price
    if coff_type == '1':
        if coff_size == '2':
            global l_cap_price
            l_cap_price = 4.95 * quant_coff
            tot_l_cap += quant_coff
        elif coff_size == '1':
            global r_cap_price
            r_cap_price = 4.40 * quant_coff
            tot_r_cap = tot_r_cap + quant_coff  
    if coff_type == '2':
        if coff_size == '2':
            global l_esp_price
            l_esp_price = 4.15 * quant_coff
            tot_l_esp += quant_coff
        elif coff_size == '1':
            global r_esp_price
            r_esp_price = 3.60 * quant_coff
            tot_r_esp += quant_coff   
    if coff_type == '3':
        if coff_size == '2':
            global l_lat_price
            l_lat_price = 4.40 * quant_coff
            tot_l_lat += quant_coff
        elif coff_size == '1':
            global r_lat_price
            r_lat_price = 3.85 * quant_coff
            tot_r_lat += quant_coff  
    if coff_type == '4':
        if coff_size == '2':
            global l_iced_c_price
            l_iced_c_price = 4.95 * quant_coff
            tot_l_iced_c_ic += quant_coff
        elif coff_size == '1':
            global r_iced_c_price
            r_iced_c_price = 4.40 * quant_coff
            tot_r_iced_c_ic += quant_coff 
    if coff_type == '5':
        if coff_size == '2':
            global l_iced_price
            l_iced_price = 4.40 * quant_coff
            tot_l_iced += quant_coff
        elif coff_size == '1':
            global r_iced_price
            (r_iced_price) = 3.85 * quant_coff
            tot_r_iced += quant_coff   
    return 

#A function to calculate the total cost of an order and the GST included within the order.
def total():
   subtotal = r_iced_price + l_iced_price + r_iced_c_price + l_iced_c_price + r_lat_price + l_lat_price + r_esp_price + l_esp_price + l_cap_price + r_cap_price
   gst = (r_iced_price/11) + (l_iced_price/11) + (r_iced_c_price/11) + (l_iced_c_price/11) + (r_lat_price/11) + (l_lat_price/11) + (r_esp_price/11) + (l_esp_price/11) + (l_cap_price/11) + (r_cap_price/11)
   print('Your Order: ')
   #Displays the order cost and the GST included in the order to the end
   print("The total cost of your order is $" + subtotal)
   print('GST included in total: $' + gst)
    
total()    

def coff_summary():
    coff_sum_ask = input('Would you like a summary of todays sales? ' )
    coff_sum_ask.lower()
    if coff_sum_ask == 'yes':
        print('TODAYS SALES:')
        print('Total Large Cappacinno Sales: ' + str(tot_l_cap))
        print('Total Regular Cappacinno Sales: ' + str(tot_r_cap))
        print('Total Large Espresso Sales: ' + str(tot_l_esp))
        print('Total Regular Espresso Sales: ' + str(tot_r_esp))
        print('Total Large Latte Sales: ' + str(tot_l_lat))
        print('Total Regular Latte Sales: ' + str(tot_r_lat))
        print("Total Large Iced Coffee's with Cream and Icecream Sales: " + str(tot_l_iced_c_ic))
        print("Total Regular Iced Coffee's with Cream and Icecream Sales: " + str(tot_r_iced_c_ic))
        print("Total Large Iced Coffee's Sales: " + str(tot_l_iced))
        print("Total Regular Iced Coffee's Sales: " + str(tot_r_iced))
    if coff_sum_ask == 'no':
        print('Okay! Have a Good Day!!')

coff_summary()
```

Comment: Also, you are not even using `coff_order()`, you are not calling/starting it.

Answer (score 1):

I made a version of your program without using functions. The difference is, that it keeps interacting with the user until they don't want to order anymore. Then it can summarize before quitting or the user can choose to create a new order etc. I tried to keep it simple and easy to read.

```
import time

def welcome():
    print('Welcome to 4Shore Cafe!\nWe are happy to be of your assistance today.\nPlease select from our fabulous menu below:\n\n')
    #Warning that customers must enter an integer - which is associated with the coffee they wish to purchase.
    print('Please be advised to enter all coffee choices with the number they are associated with :)\n')
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('Enter q or quit to exit at any time.')
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')

def prices():
    #Menu for the customers to choose from:
    print('1. Cappuccino:       |Regular: $4.40         |Large: $4.95')
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('2. Espresso:         |Regular: $3.60         |Large: $4.15')
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('3. Latte:            |Regular: $3.85         |Large: $4.40')
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('4. Iced Coffee With ice-cream and cream:          |Regular: $4.40         |Large: $4.95')
    print('5. Iced Coffee Without:                           |Regular: $3.85         |Large: $4.40')
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')

orders = {'Cappuccino':{1:4.40,2:4.95},
          'Espresso':{1:3.60,2:4.15},
          'Latte':{1:3.85,2:4.40},
          'Iced Coffee With ice-cream and cream':{1:4.40,2:4.95},
          'Iced Coffee Without':{1:3.85,2:4.40}}
order_conversion = {1:'Cappuccino',2:'Espresso',3:'Latte',4:'Iced Coffee With ice-cream and cream',5:'Iced Coffee Without'}
order_size = {1:'Regular',2:'Large'}
total_orders = {'Cappuccino':{1:0,2:0},'Espresso':{1:0,2:0},'Latte':{1:0,2:0},'Iced Coffee With ice-cream and cream':{1:0,2:0},'Iced Coffee Without':{1:0,2:0}}
total_cost = {'Cappuccino':0,'Espresso':0,'Latte':0,'Iced Coffee With ice-cream and cream':0,'Iced Coffee Without':0}
order_cost = {'Cappuccino':0,'Espresso':0,'Latte':0,'Iced Coffee With ice-cream and cream':0,'Iced Coffee Without':0}

welcome()
while True:
    prices()
    take_order = ['What coffee would you like to order? ','Would you like the size to be 1. Regular or 2. Large? ','How many would you like to order? ']
    order = ['','','']
    for i,o in enumerate(take_order):
        order[i] = input(o)
        if 'q' in order[i].lower():
            break
    if any('q' in x.lower() for x in order):
        break
    try:
        coff_type = int(order[0])
        coff_size = int(order[1])
        quant_coff = int(order[2])
    except:
        print('You can only enter numbers, try again\n')
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
    if coff_type in order_conversion:
        if not coff_size in order_size:
            print('You have not selected a correct size, try again\n')
            time.sleep(1)
            continue
        coff_type = order_conversion[coff_type]
        total_orders[coff_type][coff_size] += quant_coff
        total_cost[coff_type] += (orders[coff_type][coff_size]*quant_coff)
        order_cost[coff_type] += (orders[coff_type][coff_size]*quant_coff)
    else:
        print(f'Your order number {coff_type} couldn\'t be found.\n')
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
    add = input('Would you like to order more (yes/no)? ')
    if 'q' in add.lower(): break
    if 'n' not in add.lower():
        print()
        continue
    print(f'Your Order:\nThe total cost of your order is ${sum(order_cost.values()):.2f}\nGST included in total: ${sum(order_cost.values())/11:.2f}')
    new = input('New order (yes/no)? ')
    if 'q' in new.lower(): break
    if 'n' not in new.lower():
        order_cost = {'Cappuccino':0,'Espresso':0,'Latte':0,'Iced Coffee With ice-cream and cream':0,'Iced Coffee Without':0}
        print()
        continue
    summary = input('Would you like a summary of todays sales (yes/no)? ')
    if 'q' in summary.lower(): break
    if 'n' not in summary.lower():
        print('TODAYS SALES:')
        for key,value in total_orders.items():
            for k,v in value.items():
                print(f'Total {key} {order_size[k]} Sales: {v}')
        print(f'Total income: ${sum(total_cost.values()):.2f}\nGST included in total: ${sum(total_cost.values())/11:.2f}')
        break
    print('Okay! Have a Good Day!!')
    break
```

Test:

```
Welcome to 4Shore Cafe!
We are happy to be of your assistance today.
Please select from our fabulous menu below: 


Please be advised to enter all coffee choices with the number they are associated with :)        

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enter q or quit to exit at any time.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1. Cappuccino:       |Regular: $4.40         |Large: $4.95
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2. Espresso:         |Regular: $3.60         |Large: $4.15
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3. Latte:            |Regular: $3.85         |Large: $4.40
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4. Iced Coffee With ice-cream and cream:          |Regular: $4.40         |Large: $4.95
5. Iced Coffee Without:                           |Regular: $3.85         |Large: $4.40
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
What coffee would you like to order? 1
Would you like the size to be 1. Regular or 2. Large? 1
How many would you like to order? 2
Would you like to order more (yes/no)? 

1. Cappuccino:       |Regular: $4.40         |Large: $4.95
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2. Espresso:         |Regular: $3.60         |Large: $4.15
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3. Latte:            |Regular: $3.85         |Large: $4.40
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4. Iced Coffee With ice-cream and cream:          |Regular: $4.40         |Large: $4.95
5. Iced Coffee Without:                           |Regular: $3.85         |Large: $4.40
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
What coffee would you like to order? 2
Would you like the size to be 1. Regular or 2. Large? 2
How many would you like to order? 2
Would you like to order more (yes/no)? 

1. Cappuccino:       |Regular: $4.40         |Large: $4.95
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2. Espresso:         |Regular: $3.60         |Large: $4.15
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3. Latte:            |Regular: $3.85         |Large: $4.40
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4. Iced Coffee With ice-cream and cream:          |Regular: $4.40         |Large: $4.95
5. Iced Coffee Without:                           |Regular: $3.85         |Large: $4.40
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
What coffee would you like to order? 3
Would you like the size to be 1. Regular or 2. Large? 1
How many would you like to order? 2
Would you like to order more (yes/no)? 

1. Cappuccino:       |Regular: $4.40         |Large: $4.95
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2. Espresso:         |Regular: $3.60         |Large: $4.15
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3. Latte:            |Regular: $3.85         |Large: $4.40
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4. Iced Coffee With ice-cream and cream:          |Regular: $4.40         |Large: $4.95
5. Iced Coffee Without:                           |Regular: $3.85         |Large: $4.40
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
What coffee would you like to order? 4
Would you like the size to be 1. Regular or 2. Large? 2
How many would you like to order? 2
Would you like to order more (yes/no)? 

1. Cappuccino:       |Regular: $4.40         |Large: $4.95
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2. Espresso:         |Regular: $3.60         |Large: $4.15
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3. Latte:            |Regular: $3.85         |Large: $4.40
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4. Iced Coffee With ice-cream and cream:          |Regular: $4.40         |Large: $4.95
5. Iced Coffee Without:                           |Regular: $3.85         |Large: $4.40
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
What coffee would you like to order? 5
Would you like the size to be 1. Regular or 2. Large? 1
How many would you like to order? 2
Would you like to order more (yes/no)? n
Your Order:
The total cost of your order is $42.40
GST included in total: $3.85
New order (yes/no)? y

1. Cappuccino:       |Regular: $4.40         |Large: $4.95
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2. Espresso:         |Regular: $3.60         |Large: $4.15
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3. Latte:            |Regular: $3.85         |Large: $4.40
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4. Iced Coffee With ice-cream and cream:          |Regular: $4.40         |Large: $4.95
5. Iced Coffee Without:                           |Regular: $3.85         |Large: $4.40
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
What coffee would you like to order? 2
Would you like the size to be 1. Regular or 2. Large? 1
How many would you like to order? 4
Would you like to order more (yes/no)? 

1. Cappuccino:       |Regular: $4.40         |Large: $4.95
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2. Espresso:         |Regular: $3.60         |Large: $4.15
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3. Latte:            |Regular: $3.85         |Large: $4.40
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4. Iced Coffee With ice-cream and cream:          |Regular: $4.40         |Large: $4.95
5. Iced Coffee Without:                           |Regular: $3.85         |Large: $4.40
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
What coffee would you like to order? 5
Would you like the size to be 1. Regular or 2. Large? 2
How many would you like to order? 4
Would you like to order more (yes/no)? n
Your Order:
The total cost of your order is $32.00
GST included in total: $2.91
New order (yes/no)? n
Would you like a summary of todays sales (yes/no)? y
TODAYS SALES:
Total Cappuccino Regular Sales: 2
Total Cappuccino Large Sales: 0
Total Espresso Regular Sales: 4
Total Espresso Large Sales: 2
Total Latte Regular Sales: 2
Total Latte Large Sales: 0
Total Iced Coffee With ice-cream and cream Regular Sales: 0
Total Iced Coffee With ice-cream and cream Large Sales: 2
Total Iced Coffee Without Regular Sales: 2
Total Iced Coffee Without Large Sales: 4
Total income: $74.40
GST included in total: $6.76
```

I hope it might help. Feel free to ask any question.

Answer (score 0):

to use your global variable in another definition you need to get the variable using global declaration first

in the `def coff_order()` variable `quant_off` is not defined